# Send Message with Custom Properties with Redemption

Tags: c#, .net, outlook-addin, outlook-2007, outlook-redemption

I’m using Redemption.dll to set custom properties to my messages with set_Filed() and get_field() in C#. Everything works perfectly until the moment I send my messages.
From Outlook I use RDOMail.Send() and this sent the message to the Drafts folder. Then I read in the Redemption FAQ that I should use the IMessage::Submit() method (that I couldn’t find anywhere in the dll for .NET) and then use DeliverNow(), method that I did use but to my surprise when I receive my messages I lose the properties I had set.
This is really completely critical to our project since if Outlook can’t send mails it’s worth nothing.

Here is part of my code.

```
 private void adxOutlookEvents_ItemSend(object sender, AddinExpress.MSO.ADXOlItemSendEventArgs e)
 {
     try
     {
         RDOSessionClass _RDOSession= MessagesActions.GetRDOSession();
         Outlook.MailItem _MailItem= e.Item as Outlook.MailItem;
         RDOMail _RdoMail = MessagesActions.GetRDOMail(_RDOSession, _MailItem);
         _RdoMail.Send();                // Send using Redeption
         e.Cancel = true;                // Only send using Redeption

         if (_RdoMail != null && Marshal.IsComObject(_RdoMail))
             Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_RdoMail);

         Redemption.MAPIUtils _MAPIUtils = new MAPIUtils();
         _MAPIUtils.DeliverNow(0, 0);
         if (_MAPIUtils != null && Marshal.IsComObject(_MAPIUtils))
             Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_MAPIUtils);

         CurrentInspector.Close(Outlook.OlInspectorClose.olDiscard);
     }
     catch
     {
     }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When a message is sent through SMTP (unlike between 2 Exchange mailboxes in the same domain), the message is converted to MIME, and all MAPI specific properties are lost.

You can force Outlook to send the message in the TNEF (the infamous winmail.dat) format if yo uset a special named property called UseTnef:

RDOMail.Fields["http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8582000B"] = true;